# Unzip multiple files located in different directories to a single directory using Linux terminal

Tags: bash, gzip, unzip

Attempting to unzip several files located in different directories using linux terminal, and have extracted output be placed in one defined directory.

```
 /Dir 0
 /Dir 1
--Dir A
  zip1.zip
  zip2.zip
--Dir B
  zip3.zip
  zip4.zip
--Dir C
  zip5.zip
  zip6.zip
 /Dir 2
--Dir AA
  zip1.zip
  zip2.zip
--Dir BB
  zip3.zip
  zip4.zip
--Dir CC
  zip5.zip
  zip6.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `-d` flag of `unzip` and `bash`'s globstar globbing:

```
shopt -s globstar
for z in **/*.zip; do unzip -d output-dir "$z"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -d <dir_path> {}' ';'
```